# Not able to connect internet after manual configuration debian

Tags: debian, ethernet, dhcp

I have made Manual IP address assignment for my task and when I am trying get it back on Automatic(DHCP) it is not connecting automatically with internet.

I Don't understand from where to start debugging as I am new to linux.

Thanks for your reply.

Linux details which I am using:

*:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Debian

Description: Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)

Release: 7.8

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only have console access.

If so, have a look at /etc/network/interfaces file which contains your interfaces configuration details.

To set an interface to use DHCP, let's say eth0, focus on lines/sections explicitely mentioning eth0, delete them and simply put :

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

You'll need to be root (or sudo) to edit the file.
Save the file, return to shell, and then issue :
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0

finally, check your interface has an ip with either

```
ifconfig
```

or

```
ip addr
```

**ADDITION - Simple way to configure an interface.**

Again the in the /etc/network/interfaces file, this is what your eth0 configuration could/should look like :

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        broadcast 192.168.200.255
```